# I'm an 11 letter word - what am I?

Tags: riddle, word

I'm an 11 letter word.

> 4, 5, 6. I'm a part of your body.
>
> 7, 8, 9, 10. I contribute to your interior.
>
> 1, 2, 3, 4. You've probably heard me saying you can't hurry love.

What am I?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The answer is:

> Philippines

Part of your body:

> **Lip**

Contribute to your interior:

> **Pine**, as a christmas tree

You can't hurry love:

> Is a **Phil** Collins song

Comment: Wonderful. That's the right answer. response in 10 min great.

Comment: How in the world did you get the "contribute to your interior" part :o

Comment: @PierreArlaud I actually solved that one after I found out what the word was. I got the two other answers and figured out what the word was, and afterwards I thought of an explanation that fit the unsolved clue.

Comment: @Wu33o ok lemme rephrase that: how in the world did you think about "lip" first as body part? Tbh I would think of "leg" first

Comment: @PierreArlaud: If you've already got "Phil", you just need to go through the three-letter words starting "l" that are body parts. "'Philleg?' Hmm, nope. 'Phillip?' Ah, yes, something starts with that. Phillipines! Now I wonder what 'pines' have to do with anything.. hmm..."

Comment: @AJ: It was an example of how Wu33o may have come to the solution, as asked by Pierre.