# Another 11-letter word puzzle - what am I?

Tags: riddle, word

Inspired by this [11-letter word puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/38428/im-an-11-letter-word-what-am-i), another one goes below:

An **11-letter word** for denoting something very ancient to us.

> 1-2-3 letters: used for denoting what occurs three times, 
>   be it a championship or a geometric shape.
>
> 3-4-5 letters: what the White Witch, Sub-Zero and queen Elsa have in common?
>
> 6-7-8 letters: not a little mouse, that one. It should avoid the Vietnamese cuisine, though.
>
> 9-10-11 letters: a fertility deity, but also commonly adopted by military.

What am I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Voila

> Triceratops, RAWR
>  Tri - 3 of a kind
>  ice - theye are all icy, throw in frozone for good measure
>  rat - rats are big (some teach turtles), in vietnam they ought to beware the rat snake
>  ops - operations (see: Black ops), the fertility deity is Ops or Opis, a latin deity. (Opis meant plenty)
>  Triceratops are arguably quite ancient having died ought round about 60 odd million years ago but some triassic dinos would likely disagree.

Comment: Was in the process of typing this :( Oh well, +1.

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering if I should have just gotten the answer in and then added my extraneous information, but I took the risk.

Answer (score 1):

The answer:

> 1-2-3: tri
>  3-4-5: ice
>  6-7-8: rat
>  9-10-11: ops

Comment: You're right, but someone was faster. And please, add spoiler tags.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE. Please have a [tour of the site](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) and [use >! in the starting of the line](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/58/spoiler-markup-required?rq=1) to add spoilers so that they are temporarily hidden from others.

Comment: @ABcDexter Please note that the site has no rule or consensus about requiring spoiler tags.  Also, [spoiler-only edits](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3065) should be avoided.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain Ohh, my bad. I will take it into notice :)